# Using rsync to mirror folders on NAS

Tags: backup, sync, cron, rsync

I have an old netbook that I use as a torrent server running utorrent on ubuntu and accessing with the webUI, at the moment I add links through the UI and then manually copy the files over to my NAS.

What I'd like to be able to do is set utorrent to move completed downloads into a folder where everything that's there is copied to my NAS, ideally using a crontab to do it every so often so I don't have to run it manually. Sadly I know almost nothing about linux and al my attempts have failed.

Is this possible/ how can I go about achieving this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  Please take the tour at https://askubuntu.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.

Comment: Here is a Q&A discussing making copies of full filesystems.  It should be easy enough to modify to mirror only specific directories:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/939677/ubuntu-16-04-rsync-via-ssh-prompts-me-for-password-how-to-make-it-a-cron-job

Answer (score 0):

Of course running `rsync` via cron job is an option, but it is NOT the best option.

You can try [BitTorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync) (AKA btsync), download and run btsync on both your old netbook and NAS (most likely to be running ARM Linux), set up folder to sync on the old netbook, add then add it (use the secret or QR code) on the NAS to sync it over. Works like a charm.